# continuity equation involving vectors

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces, physics, vector-analysis, electromagnetism

A time dependent point charge $q\left ( t \right )$ at the origin $\rho\left ( \vec{r},t \right )=q\left ( t \right )\delta ^{3}\left ( \vec{r} \right ) $, is fed by a current $\vec{J}\left ( \vec{r},t \right )=-\left ( \frac{1}{4 \pi} \right )\left ( \frac{\dot{q}}{r^{2}} \right )\hat{r}$
where $\dot{q}=\frac{\mathrm{dq} }{\mathrm{d} t}$

I want to determine that $\bigtriangledown \cdot \vec{J}=\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}$ but the integrals are giving me a terribly hard time.

Here's my attempt:
$\vec{\bigtriangledown} \cdot \vec{J}=0$

$\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}$, as I've worked, is $\dot{q}\delta ^{3}\left ( \vec{r} \right )$

but it doesn't seem to satisfy the continuity equation.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Was my answer sufficient, or is there some detail I can help clarify?

Answer (score 1):

The divergence of $\hat{r}/r^2$ is not zero, in fact it is equal to $4\pi\delta^{(3)}(\vec{r})$. This fact can be found in the early chapters of most electrodynamics texts.